# How can I stop the Minecraft Launcher from downloading java?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

Every time I launch the new native Minecraft launcher it downloads java, and right after that I delete it. I already have java installed, I don't want it to be installed again. I also already have my profile set to use my already-installed java, it works fine.

How can I stop it from downloading the java runtime every time I start it?

Comment: Wondering if using [MultiMC](https://multimc.org/) gives you this option

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.  The real question is why you care, this version is only used by the game itself and cannot be used to open other executable JAR files.
EDIT:
it may be possible to place another executable as a placeholder, so Minecraft thinks that the JRE is there, but it is not.

Comment: I think it's a reasonable question, since lots of people are strapped for storage space, installing to versions of Java runtime is obviously going to take up more space

Comment: Also, not everybody has a broadband Internet connection with unlimited data usage. Redownloading the JRE every time without needing it, is a huge waste of bandwidth, time, and possibly money.

Comment: You could always not delete it every time, and the JRE that comes with minecraft is less then 50 mb

Comment: however I thought of something that may or may not work, and added it